# Check Differentiability at a point

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

I am supposed to check the differentiability of the function

$f(x) = x\cdot \text{sin}(x)\cdot \text{sin}(1/x)$ and $f(0) =0$ at the point $x=0$.

I know that $\lim_{x \to 0} x\cdot \text{sin}(1/x)$ = $\lim_{x \to 0} x\cdot \text{sin}(1/x) = 0$.

Tried using the definition of proving the Left and Right Hand derivates to be equal, but getting stuck.

Answer (score 4):

Clearly, $f$ is differentiable in any point except $0$. To study the differentiability in $0$ just use the definition:
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x \cdot \text{sin}(x) \cdot \text{sin}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \ \text{sin}(x) \cdot \text{sin}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) =0$$
since $\text{sin}(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow 0$ and $\text{sin}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ is bounded.

Comment: So, this means the functions is differentiable at x=$0$ right?

Comment: Yes, and the derivative at $x=0$ is $0$.